# How to get data with primary key from other table in NAVISION

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-nav, dynamics-nav-2016

I want to make a report in a payment journal that displays the data of the bank account name used by the vendor in the Vendor Bank Account table (288). Where vendors have chosen bank accounts in filed 'prefered bank accounts' on Vendor table (23)

My Code,

```
IF R_VendorBank.GET(AccountNo) THEN
  BankAccountVendor := R_VendorBank.Name
ELSE
  CLEAR(BankAccountVendor);
```

Note : R_VendorName type Record lookup to Vendor Bank Account Table, BankAccountVendor type Text.

How can I get the value of the bank name used by the vendor in the Vendor Bank Account table (288) ?

Comment: Most probably the table has two fields in the primary key. Vendor and Bank Account. So `GET` needs two parameters.

Comment: How to get table with 2 parameters sir ? Thanks for advice.

Comment: Like this `VendorBank.GET(VendorNo, AccountNo)`. And I’d advise to stick to Cronus naming conventions. Don’t use prefixes like `R_`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics-nav/get-function--record-) for documentation where it is said that `Record.GET([Value] ,...)`. The `,...` part means that number of parameters may be more than one.